# Javascript image uploading issue

Tags: javascript

I have this issue with a script that I was developing, to upload images on a canvas and with the cursor make it pass like a carousel

```
VM20:158 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'
    at draw (<anonymous>:158:57)
```

when I go to the line that is pointing the problem

```
if (imgArray.length == sprite.cols * sprite.rows) {
  ctx.drawImage(imgArray[ci], 0, 0);
}
```

but when I re-do it for the second time (that means pressing F5 and  uploading the images again)
it works

the code that is being skipped in the first time is

```
 function showFile() {
  var fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');

  for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (readerEvent) {
      var listItem = document.createElement('li');

      imagenes.push(readerEvent.target.result);
      image_load = 'si';
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[i]);
  }
}
```

The question is: why it works only when i re-do the process again and not at the first time?.

Source on Google sites

https://sites.google.com/view/pruebamodelado/home

the pictures are at https://sites.google.com/view/pruebamodelado/fotos-test-downlaod?authuser=0

Comment: You need to include more of your code. How do the images get from `imagenes.push(readerEvent.target.result)` to `imgArray`? Try debugging it by checking the length of the array after loading the files, and logging the `ci` variable used as the index. What do you get? Is the array empty, or is the `ci` index out of bounds?

Comment: already tried debugging, if you go to the website https://sites.google.com/view/pruebamodelado/home, and go to developers tools the code is there

Answer (score 0):

```js
reader.onload = function (e) {
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");

    img.src = e.target.result;

  imagenes.push(img.src);
  image_load="si"                       
}
```

You're creating a race condition here, and also pushing the `src` string to the array instead of the image. Before an image can be drawn to a canvas it has to be loaded, and you're not listening to the load event. The outcome is that sometimes the images have had enough time to load, and sometimes they did not, causing the error. It can work the second time because your browser is probably caching the images and they load faster. You can solve it like this:

```js
reader.onload = function (e) {
  var img = document.createElement("IMG");
  img.onload = () => {
    imagenes.push(img);
    image_load="si" 
  }
  img.src = e.target.result;                    
}
```

EDIT: Now I see that you're creating another `Image` instance from the src later in the code, but the same problem happens there as well - you need to listen to the `load` event before you can draw it on a canvas.

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.
    at draw (file://pathxxx/scriptnuevopaginamodelado.html:213:57)

error still occurring after adding your code