# Tkinter command button with args

Tags: python, tkinter, arguments

I have this entry box in tkinter:

```
lbl1 = Label(window, text="Escribe un nombre" , font=("Arial Bold", 12))
lbl1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

textBox = Entry(window, width=10)
textBox.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

btn3 = Button(window, text="Guardar Nombre")# -n
btn3.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
```

and I want to make the button "Guardar Nombre" command that when the user write the name of the output file, do the following arg

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-n','--nombre', help='Nombre del archivo', required=True)
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "do the following arg"?

Comment: without the tkinter the .py program that i added to the GUI program, when i execute asks me for the name of the file "parser.add_argument('-n','--nombre', help='Nombre del archivo', required=True)" the quantity of the photos on the x axis and the quantity of the y axis, so if i want for example to run the program without the GUI and only by parameters on the terminal i write  "python3 nameoftheprogram.py -n nameoftheoutputfile -x "quantity of the photos in the x axis" -y "quantity of columns of the canvas" , so i want to make that instead of using a terminal to execute the .py make it GUI app

Comment: so in order to create the GUI software, i created that entry for the name 
textBox = Entry(window, width=10)
and the button to save the name as indicated in the parser.add_argument
btn3 = Button(window, text="Guardar Nombre")# -n

Comment: To answer your question we need to know how the value in the `Entry` is used by the rest of your script. It has nothing to do with `argparse`, which is just a tool for handling command-line arguments (not what is done with them _after_ they are retrieved). For this reason, your question can't be answered in its present form.

Comment: One approach to do this would be to create a _completely separate_ GUI script that allowed the user to specify what arguments to pass to the `nameoftheprogram.py` script which it can run and pass it the arguments gathered via the GUI interface.

Comment: and how i do that(One approach to do this ...) ? can i send you the code in  private ?

Comment: Sorry, no private help. To implement something like this, have a "Submit" `Button` to the GUI script that executes a function when clicked that takes all the information entered by the user and runs the other script passing the data gathered as command-line arguments to it. There's more than one way to execute another script and pass it arguments — using the `subprocess` module is a very good one, and there are numerous examples of using it on this site (as well as in many tutorials).

Comment: so i added import subprocess on top, then created a function 

def submit():
 os.system("python3 nameofpyprogram.py " + "-n "+ textNameBox.get() + "-x " + numXBox.get() + "-y " + numYBox.get())

after all the boxes declarated i want to test the button by print like this

btn = Button(window, text="Submit" , command= print())

But it doesn't print anything

Comment: It's very difficult to debug code posted in comments. Either add it to your question or ask a new question. That's said, doing `...command= print()` is calling the `print()` function as the `Button` is being created and when you click it later you will get an error.

Comment: It worked martineau!!!!! Thank you so much !!!! now i have to add another function that instead of importing the images from the computer, do it from several url, (10 urls) i created this..

def clicked():
    import tempfile
    import urllib.request

    with urllib.request.urlopen('url') as response:
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp_file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(response, tmp_file)
    with open(tmp_file.name) as html:
        pass
        import shutil
but it doesnt work

Comment: That's good to hear — congratulations! You should post it as an answer to your own question (there may be a waiting period before you can do this however).

Comment: I added you on linkedin maybe i can ask you something work related

Comment: @martineau i have this question pending too, can you help me ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65041934/javascript-image-uploading-issue

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user martineau and some Googling i could sort this out

using

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
```

and created a function

```
def submit():
    x1 = textNameBox.get()
    x2 = numXBox.get()
    x3 = numYBox.get()
    os.system("python3 parse.py " + " -n"+ textNameBox.get() + " -x" + numXBox.get() + " -y" + numYBox.get())
```

and finally the button

```
btn = Button(window, text="nameofbutton" , command= submit) 
btn.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
```

although maybe x1,x2,x3 doesnt need to be (?)

It worked!